# Show only every second grid line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I started with this example to show grid lines in my line chart

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c506ac45617cf9ed39337f99f8511218

I would like to keep the automatic number of ticks for the y axis. However, I would like to show only every second grid line for the y axis.

Note that using a fixed number for the ticks() method does not work since I don't know how many ticks get rendered for the axis. Using a fixed number for grid lines usually leads to misaligned grid lines and axis ticks.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Is it maybe possible to hide every second grid line by setting its opacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this with a simple CSS selector?

```
.tick:nth-of-type(2n) line {
  display: none;
}
```

This selects every nth (2nd) tick, and changes the display style of the line.

Comment: After doing a few more tests it turns out that this is the better answer because it also works when the chart is zoomed!

Comment: @NicolasR thanks for changing your accepted answer if you felt it was a better fit :) Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, tweaking the argument passed to `ticks()` can be a real pain in the neck because, as stated in the documentation, this method *"returns **approximately** count representative values from the scale’s domain"* (emphasis mine).

Therefore, a possible solution along the lines of...

> Is it maybe possible to hide every second grid line by setting its opacity?

... is selecting those `<line>`s and using the modulo operator with their indices:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_gridlines()
        .tickSize(-width)
        .tickFormat("")
    ).selectAll("line")
    .style("opacity", function(_, i) {
        return i % 2 ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

Here is the forked bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/918c519b8dfb44e9310bc3663f3e546f/12271125ac978db93c550a32745192c469385dfb

Comment: I first selected this answer but then changed it to Ians because it works with zooming.